# Detect if a string contains any numbers

Tags: php, numbers, range, detect

This is the test.php file:

```
$string = 'A string with no numbers';

for ($i = 0; $i <= strlen($string)-1; $i++) {
    $char = $string[$i];
    $message_keyword = in_array($char, range(0,9)) ? 'includes' : 'desn\'t include';
}

// output
echo sprintf('This variable %s number(s)', codeStyle($message_keyword));

// function
function codeStyle($string) {
    return '<span style="background-color: #eee; font-weight: bold;">' . $string . '</span>';
}
```

It splits the string character by character and checks if the character is a number or not.

Problem: Its output is *always* "This variable **includes** number(s)". Please help me to find the reason.
TIP: When I change `range(0,9)` to `range(1,9)` It works correctly (But it can't detect 0).

Comment: you are always resetting `$message_keyword` on each loop, by the time you get to checking it it is the value of the last loop

Comment: @Patrick Evans: Yes, You're right. But the last character is not a number. Why does it return "includes"?

Comment: take a look at the answers below, particularly hek2mgl and dec-null-dweller's, they explain about php's type comparisons

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use `preg_match()`:

```
if (preg_match('~[0-9]+~', $string)) {
    echo 'string with numbers';
}
```

---

Althought you should not use it, as it is much slower than `preg_match()` I will explain why your original code is not working:

A non numerical character in the string when compared to a number (`in_array()` does that internally) would be evaluated as `0` what is a number. Check this example:

```
var_dump('A' == 0); // -> bool(true)
var_dump(in_array('A', array(0)); // -> bool(true)
```

Correct would be to use `is_numeric()` here:

```
$keyword = 'doesn\'t include';
for ($i = 0; $i <= strlen($string)-1; $i++) {
    if(is_numeric($string[$i]))  {
       $keyword = 'includes';
       break;
    }
}
```

Or use the string representations of the numbers:

```
$keyword = 'doesn\'t include';
// the numbers as stings
$numbers = array('0', '1', '2', /* ..., */ '9');

for ($i = 0; $i <= strlen($string)-1; $i++) {
    if(in_array($string[$i], $numbers)){
       $keyword = 'includes';
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are both `is_numeric()` and `in_array()` are slower than `preg_match()` in this case?

Comment: Yeah the problem is the loop that iterates over each char.

Comment: would it not work if you used === instead of == in your example? EDIT: lol did not see this is from 2013. was there === already in 2013?

Comment: Yes, `var_dump('A'===0)` will produce `bool(false)` but the original question was about `in_array()`

Comment: Why not `preg_match('~\d~', $string)` instead of `preg_match('~[0-9]+~', $string)`?

Answer (score 12):

You can just use [regexp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) :

```
$message_keyword = preg_match('/\d/', $string) ? 'includes' : 'desn\'t include';
```

Answer (score 4):

It's kinda late to answer this question after about 9 years, but If you want to detect integers (and not floats) nothing is better than `ctype_digit`. Using this function to detect floats with decimal point or other types would results in returning `false`.

```php
<?php
$number = "123";
$notNumber = "123abc";
var_dump(ctype_digit($number));
var_dump(ctype_digit($notNumber));
?>
```

#### Output

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, though. `ctype_digit()` only returns true if *every* character is numeric, not if the string *contains* a numeric character. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php

Answer (score 2):

Better way is using regular expression

```
<?php
    if (preg_match('#[0-9]#',$string)){
        $message_keyword = 'includes';
    }
    else{
        $message_keyword = 'desn\'t include';
    }  
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because of PHP loose type comparison, you are comparing string with integer, so PHP internally will cast this string to integer, and all character in your string will be casted to 0.

First step to fix your code, will be to create an array of strings instead of integers:

```
$numbers = array_map(function($n){ return (string)$n; }, range(0,9));
for ($i = 0; $i <= strlen($string)-1; $i++) {
    $char = $string[$i];
    $message_keyword = in_array($char,$numbers)?'includes' : 'doesn\'t include';
}
```

This will fix your case, but will not work as you expect it to, since `$message_keyword` is overwritten on each loop, so will receive message for last character only. If you are aiming to only check if string contains number, you can stop checking after encountering first number:

```
$message_keyword = 'doesn\'t include';
for ($i = 0; $i <= strlen($string)-1; $i++) {
    $char = $string[$i];
    if(in_array($char, $numbers)) {
        $message_keyword = 'includes';
        break; //found, no need to check next
    }   
}
```

To have this all logic in more compact form, use regular expresion, as posted by others before.

Comment: Nice and clear! What does this mean exactly? `$numbers = array_map(function($n){ return (string)$n; }, range(0,9));`

Comment: This takes array of integers created by `range` and casts every element to string, so you have an array of string to compare against.

Answer (score 0):

```
array range ( mixed $start , mixed $end [, number $step = 1 ] )
```

If a `step` value is given, it will be used as the increment between `elements` in the sequence. `step` should be given as a `positive number`. If not **specified**, step will default to `1`.

In your case, you havent mentioned the third parameter that is why it is always set to `1`

See [Manual here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)